# Icalendar file (.ics) queries on the font-face

Tags: email, icalendar

When creating a ".ics" file and opening on notepad, there would be this particular line that talks bout the mso-font-signature under the @font-face portion. May I ask what does the 32 numbers behind mso-font -signature means?

An example is as shown below.

"mso-font-signature:-520092929 1073786111 9 0 415 0;"

Comment: An ics file shouldn't contain thes data. `mso-xyz` are formating data used in Microsoft Office Applications like Outlook or Word. See this [sample ics file structure](https://gist.github.com/DeMarko/6142417). Maybe you have pasted your ics code in Word? You should rather use a dedicated code editor like visual studio code, notepad++ etc. (fortunately, there is no shortage of free code editors).

Comment: Yes. I am using a Microsoft office application. Do you know what does that specific set of numbers for mso-font-signature represents?